# How to maximise the time, in which javascript code would be made readable by a hacker?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I am searching for creative ways to obfuscate my JS code, so the users couldn't "beautify" it in less than 1 hour.

To be specific, I have an array, values of which I need to hide from the users, who understand JS, for one hour at least. At this point, I am going to use ascii codes and Caesar cipher, for example. Any more creative ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Ciphers and things probably won't work that well. Just replace `eval` with `console.log` or `alert` and you've got the unciphered code.

Comment: icktoofay, good point. will try to consider this. tvanfosson, I am  making a game interface, where users will be given an hour to enter correct answers to different text inputs, and based on the answers, the fields backgrounds will change with certain picture, which I also need to hide.

Comment: @Jevgeni -  The difficulty, as I see it, is eventually someone figures out your algorithm, unless you vary it a lot, and is able to quickly decipher the text no matter how complicated the algorithm is if you make the data available in the browser.  I'd try to work out a way to keep the data on the server. Maybe use some AJAX to validate responses against data on the server and send back encrypted image references to use with a controller to allow the display of the background images?

Comment: @tvanfosson Thank You for Your answer, but I don't have any access to this server, unfortunately. I would gladly make AJAX calls to other server, if it only would be possible ...

Comment: @Jevgeni - you're serving up the JS but not the web page? Seems a little confusing to me.  You could always use JSONP and an alternate server for the images.

Comment: JSONP is good thought - thanks, i will look into it! Yes, I have a platform, that allows me to create pages with HTML, CSS and JS, but doesn't allow server scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hashing algorithm, and only store the hashed result of the correct answer. To compare the entered answer to the correct answer, hash the entered answer and compare the hash codes. Although not completely safe, it will take some serious time to crack.

This of course requires that there are a lot of possible answers. For a question like *"Which year was N.N. born?"*, you could easily brute force every possible answer in less than a second.

Comment: How can somebody brute force all the numbers that fast? :) programmicaly ?

Comment: @Jevgeni Bogatyrjov: Of course. It takes a minute or so to build a page with a loop that calls the hashing function, and a second to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a series of noise patterns that aren't used in the contents of the array and eliminate them with various regexps.  But why on earth would you want to do this?  Please tell me that this isn't for a production environment.  Obscurity is not security.

Comment: I suspect it's for some sort of contest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extensive use of the comma operator, confusing shortcircuits, loops, prefix and postfix incrementing that doesn't do what it looks like it should, and making really good use of the way the assignment operator is evaluated left-to-right. For example:

```
j=(a=[],i=0);while(i-10)a[i++]=++j+i;
```

Would give 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20. It might not seem that confusing but can really be great depending on the size of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to use the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode (**NOT** Simple Mode).

A JavaScript program processed by the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode is next to impossible to reverse-engineer, even after passing through a beautifier.

The downside is that there are many many restrictions when using Advanced Mode.  For those who can use it, it is definitely worth it.

I personally use the Dojo Toolkit and have my mobile programs optimized by the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode.  It makes the resulting files around 25% smaller than simple minification (which can be beaten by a beautifier) due to dead-code removal, inlining, virtualization, namespace flattening etc.  Performance is also enhanced because of the vigorous optimizations.  I regularly put the resulting files through numerous beautifiers to make sure that they cannot be easily reversed-engineered.